# Yarn workspace + lerna is creating node_modules in each sub-package

Tags: yarnpkg, lerna, monorepo

I have a monorepo which I'm managing with yarn workspaces + lerna. From what I understand, running `yarn` should create a `node_modules` directory at the root of the project but *not* in each individual package. I was following a tutorial where the author says this:

> yarn workspaces creates only one node_modules folder. All dependencies are hoisted to the root folder

Is this assumption always true? Or is there a case where yarn + lerna will create individual `node_modules` directories in each package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read a few articles and was confused with the same thing.

The short answer is, you are right. Yarn creates `node_modules` for each package along with a `node_modules` directory in the root of your repo.

In other words, Yarn creates `/packages/<package>/node_modules` in all your packages. However, the `/packages/<package>/node_modules` directory will be optimized by reusing dependencies that are in `/node_modules`. This is basically what these authors are trying to say!

To sum it up, you will have `n + 1` `node_modules` directories, where `n` is the number of packages you have, assuming all your packages have dependencies.

Let's consider an example:

```
yarn workspace package-1 add commander
```

would not create `/packages/package-1/node_modules/commander` if it's already in `/node_modules/commander` with compatible versions.

Now let's look at another case:

```
yarn workspace package-1 add chalk
```

If Yarn cannot reuse what's in `/node_modules`, it will install the package locally, which in our case is `/packages/package-1/node_modules/chalk`.

You can read more about this in Yarn's official blog: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2017/08/02/introducing-workspaces/